# Sockets in windows with cygwin

Tags: c++, c, sockets, cygwin

I am facing a problem working with cygwin and sockets under windows. 
The code is working normaly in Ubuntu but when I am running it under windows, the socket will not open (error 10093) because no WSAStartup call was made. But when I include winsock.h for WSAStartup i cant even compile because of an conflicting declaration of `int select(int, _types_fd_set*, _types_fd_set*, _types_fd_set*, PTIMEVAL)` in winsock and unistd .

however does anyone know a way to get sockets run with cygwin???

thanks

Comment: You should probably better stick to `boost::asio`.

Comment: As a workaround you can create separate file which include `winsock.h`, but not `unistd.h` and perform winsock initialization there. Dunno how it should work intially, though.

Comment: I would prefer not to take  boost because I also want it to run on Android later on and I boost was not the best with Android ... Okey creating a seperate file could work but is not the most beautiful solution

Comment: Time for a #define..

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Does cygwin's POSIX compatibility layer need WSAStartup? Strikes me as kind of odd.

Comment: I thought not but creating a socket returns the error 10093 which is for not calling the wsastartup ...

Comment: Try this: Back up all of your code. Replace all of the Windows and winsock includes with the posix sys/types.h, sys/socket.h, etc... Make sure you are calling the POSIX versions instead of the Windows stuff. If it works, awesome. If it doesn't, restore backup.

Comment: okey i'lll try !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess up cygwin with windows libs an everything works fine! Since I am not including any windows lib, the UNIX sockets work fine.

Thanks to user4581301.

Answer (score -1):

put _winsock_deprecated_no_warnings in defines and #include < winsock2.h >

Comment: did you put the #define in the preprocessor defines? or just type it into your code?